# ASP.Net MVC Facebook-like activity stream

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, social-networking, feed, activity-streams

I would like to implement facebook - like news feed for my website, with social functionalities, such as share, like, comment and post and I want to connect it to already created users (nice to have it connected with Azure Active Directory).
Is there any ready solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DLeh: That's a little harsh. While the question is off-topic for StackOverflow, libraries such as what the OP wants do exist. I used one in a Django project I was working on, but of course, that was specific to Django and doesn't help the OP here with ASP.NET. The point though is that the potential for such a library exists, just again, StackOverflow isn't the place to find it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anything specific, and StackOverflow is not the place for generalized library recommendations. However, it should be trivial enough to implement yourself. Activity streams are composed of four main components:

- Actor
- Verb
- Object
- Target

For example: "John (actor) shared (verb) a photo (object) with Mary (target)."

Just create an entity that can track these four aspects, and then add a record describing the action each time something happens. By making certain parts foreign keys (actor/target could be foreign keys to your user table), you can then pull actions specifically related to a particular user or other object in your system.